# Calculate moving RMS with exponential averaging

Tags: filters, modulation, smoothing

This is **moving RMS**, now how to add *exponential* averaging in this

`df['signal'].rolling(21*24*60).apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x.mean()))`

Answer (score 1):

```
n_d =  pd.DataFrame((data)**2)

np.sqrt(n_d.ewm(alpha = 1).mean())
```